# Android view states: pressed, activated, selected etc. bindings. Do I have to write custom bindings?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Binding a boolean (HasLiked) to Pressed from viewmodel results in error:

```
Failed to create target binding for from HasLiked to Pressed
```

Does it mean that android View.Pressed (and other states) bindings by MvxBind aren't supported by default? Do i need to write custom bindings?

**EDIT- binding:**

```
<RelativeLayout
        style="@style/ButtonExtraSocial"
        android:background="@drawable/SelectorButtonExtra"
        app:MvxBind="Click LikeCommand; Pressed HasLiked">
....
</RelativeLayout>
```

HasLiked boolean exist in viewmodel (when I bind it to TextView text, I get the value).

Comment: Works fine here, can you please show your binding description?

Comment: I thought that it should work fine too... I updated my question.

Comment: What trace do you get? Basic answer is if it's `EventHandler` the binding will work, but if it's `EventHandler<T>` then you have to write a custom binding (it's not hard)

Answer (score 4):

I can't seem to reproduce your problem here. I have created a very simple sample, which does what you ask for.

**FirstViewModel.cs**

```
public class FirstViewModel 
    : MvxViewModel
{
    public FirstViewModel()
    {
        IsPressed = true;
    }

    private string _hello = "Hello MvvmCross";
    public string Hello
    { 
        get { return _hello; }
        set { _hello = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Hello); }
    }

    public bool _isPressed;
    public bool IsPressed
    {
        get { return _isPressed; }
        set { _isPressed = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsPressed); }
    }
}
```

**FirstView.cs**

```
[Activity(Label = "View for FirstViewModel")]
public class FirstView : MvxActivity
{
    public new FirstViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return (FirstViewModel)base.ViewModel; }
        set { base.ViewModel = value; }
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.FirstView);

        var button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button);
        button.Click += (sender, args) => ViewModel.IsPressed = !ViewModel.IsPressed;
    }
}
```

**FirstView.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    local:MvxBind="Text Hello"
    />
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    local:MvxBind="Text Hello"
    />
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    local:MvxBind="Text Hello; Pressed IsPressed"/>
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    local:MvxBind="Pressed IsPressed"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**bg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_pressed"
      android:state_pressed="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_normal"/>
</selector>
```

**bg_normal.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
</shape>
```

**bg_pressed.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <solid android:color="#FF00FF" />
</shape>
```

This produces these two different visual states:

[image: First State]
[image: Second State]

As you see it starts with `IsPressed` being true and when I click the button it becomes false. I have verified that it works the other way around as well.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Stuart and Cheesebaron for your answers but I found out what was the real cause of this problem: packaging settings in Xamarin studio: ´Use shared mono runtime´ has to be enabled (I think by default it is checked, but I had it unchecked).

*You can access packaging settings by right click on project (not solution!) > properties > Android Build > Use shared Mono runtime.*